# C#: bitwise operator in enum (Custom Authorization in MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, operators

I'm currently reading [an article](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2009/02/17/custom-authorization-with-aspnet-mvc/) , but I do not really understand how this work with the logical operator. Can anyone explain this to me?

eg. If I want to have 4 level securities with customer, employee, supervisor and Admin.

```
[Serializable]
[Flags]
public enum WebRoles
{             
    customer= 1 << 0,
    employee= 1 << 1,
    supervisor = 1 << 2,
    Admin = 2 << 3
}
```

and then how I should implement the following logic.

```
if (Roles != 0 && ((Roles & role) != role))
            return false;
```

Can anyone provide me some knowledge of this implementation?

Thank you very much.

Daoming

Comment: You seem confused about what "logical" and "bitwise" operators are. Using the wrong terminology will make it a lot harder for your to find correct information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example uses the bitwise shift operator: "<<". This operator takes the bits and shifts them. For example, "1 << 3" results in the number 8. So, in binary,

```
customer =    0001
employee =    0010
supervisor =  0100
admin =       1000 (I think this was supposed to read 1 << 3)
```

Now, you can assign people multiple roles using the bitwise-or operator. This would be a single vertical-bar "|". The bitwise or combines the two numbers bit-by-bit, setting each bit that is set in either of the two operands.

```
myRole = customer | employee = 0011
```

The if-statement you have is intended to tell whether someone has a particular role. It uses bitwise-and: "&". Bitwise-and combines the two numbers, setting a bit only if the bit is set in both the operands.

Answer (score 19):

They're using an `enum` as a bit map: if a specific bit is set, so you have that privilege. They're also using a left shift operator. Let me try to demonstrate all that at once:

```
Role         Decimal   Binary   Shifted   Decimal
--------     -------   ------   -------   -------
Customer   =    1    = 000001 = 000001  =    1
Employee   =    1    = 000001 = 000010  =    2
Supervisor =    1    = 000001 = 000100  =    4
Admin      =    2    = 000010 = 010000  =   16
```

This way you can combine two roles. For instance, some user can play `Employee` and `Supervisor` at same time, just having correspondent bits set.

And how to check if a bit is set? It's exactly what that `(Roles & role) != role)` do. For example:

```
WebRoles user = WebRoles.Employee | WebRoles.Supervisor;
bool isEmployee = (user & WebRoles.Employee) == WebRoles.Employee; // true
```

If you test user variable to check if that `Employee` bit is set, that `&` operator will return all match bits.

Hope this help; feel free to edit this answer