# What is operation in enum type?

Tags: objective-c, operation

What is:

```
NSStreamEventOpenCompleted = 1 << 0 ,  1 << 1  , 1 << 2 , 1 << 3 , 1 << 4 ?
```

In the example below

```
typedef enum {
   NSStreamEventNone = 0,
   NSStreamEventOpenCompleted = 1 << 0,
   NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable = 1 << 1,
   NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable = 1 << 2,
   NSStreamEventErrorOccurred = 1 << 3,
   NSStreamEventEndEncountered = 1 << 4
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [bitwise shift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/141873/1181886) operation.  It is used so that you can set one or more flags from the enum.   This answer has a good explanation:  [Why use the Bitwise-Shift operator for values in a C enum definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999922/why-use-the-bitwise-shift-operator-for-values-in-a-c-enum-definition)

Basically, it's so that one integer can store multiple flags which can be checked with the binary AND operator.  The enum values end up looking like this:

```
typedef enum {
   NSStreamEventNone = 0,                      // 00000
   NSStreamEventOpenCompleted = 1 << 0,        // 00001
   NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable = 1 << 1,    // 00010
   NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable = 1 << 2,    // 00100
   NSStreamEventErrorOccurred = 1 << 3,        // 01000
   NSStreamEventEndEncountered = 1 << 4        // 10000
};
```

So you can say:

```
// Set two flags with the binary OR operator
int flags =   NSStreamEventEndEncountered | NSStreamEventOpenCompleted  // 10001

if (flags & NSStreamEventEndEncountered) // true 
if (flags & NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable) // false
```

If you didn't  have the binary shift, the values could clash or overlap and the technique wouldn't work.  You may also see enums get set to `0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16`, which is the same thing as the shift above.

Comment: Actually `(flags & NSStreamEventNone)` is false :-)