# C - Enumeration - Definition

Tags: c, enums, bit-shift

I see in  C source code where the author define enum as follows

```
enum {
    BINDER_DEBUG_USER_ERROR             = 1U << 0,
    BINDER_DEBUG_FAILED_TRANSACTION     = 1U << 1,
    BINDER_DEBUG_DEAD_TRANSACTION       = 1U << 2,
    BINDER_DEBUG_OPEN_CLOSE             = 1U << 3,
};
```

What is the logical reason behind this?

Comment: Making a series of masks using bitshift.

Comment: You might like the question [Why use the Bitwise-Shift operator for values in a C enum definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999922/why-use-the-bitwise-shift-operator-for-values-in-a-c-enum-definition/3999962#3999962).

Comment: I think main purpose is what ever author require he would set in enum.Any thing you can set. So basically author requirement is masking using above enum defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its purpose is that every entry in the enum has one bit, so you can toggle each entry:

```
/* BINDER_DEBUG_USER_ERROR = 0b0000 */
enum foo {
    BINDER_DEBUG_USER_ERROR             = 1U << 0, // = 0b0001
    BINDER_DEBUG_FAILED_TRANSACTION     = 1U << 1, // = 0b0010
    BINDER_DEBUG_DEAD_TRANSACTION       = 1U << 2, // = 0b0100
    BINDER_DEBUG_OPEN_CLOSE             = 1U << 3, // = 0b1000
};
```

And now you can set/unset several of these flags in a variable by doing logical bit operations.

For example, you can set the `FAILED_TRANSACTION` and the `OPEN_CLOSE` by doing a logical `OR`:

```
enum foo x = BINDER_DEBUG_DEAD_TRANSACTION | BINDER_DEBUG_OPEN_CLOSE;
```

Answer (score 2):

It makes it easier to see what bit is set to "1" but you would get the same result by assignment of a decimal value corresponding to bit you want to set to "1".
To answer your question, there is a reason, and it's readibility.