# Flags and << operation on enums? C#

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation

Ok so I am new to C#, and for the life of me I cannot comprehend what exactly the below code (from a legacy project) is supposed to do:

```
[Flags]
public enum EAccountStatus
{
    None = 0,
    FreeServiceApproved = 1 << 0,
    GovernmentAccount = 1 << 1,
    PrivateOrganisationAccount = 1 << 2,
    All = 8
}
```

What exactly does the `<<` operator do here on the enums? Why do we need this?

Comment: Please check pmg's answer on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999922/why-use-the-bitwise-shift-operator-for-values-in-a-c-enum-definition

Comment: Just wondering why didn't he use `All = 1 << 3` ?

Comment: Thanks @manish, that is also a brilliant answer there :)

Comment: All should be defined as FreeServiceApproved | GovernmentAccount | PrivateOrganisationAccount = 7, not 8 :(

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Behind the scenes, the enumeration is actually an int.
`<<` is the [Bitwise Left Shift Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xftzc7e(v=vs.100).aspx)
An equivalent way of writing this code is :

```
[Flags]
public enum EAccountStatus
{
    None = 0,
    FreeServiceApproved = 1,
    GovernmentAccount = 2,
    PrivateOrganisationAccount = 4,
    All = 8
}
```

Please note, that this enumeration has the [Flag attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

As stated in the msdn:

> Use the FlagsAttribute custom attribute for an enumeration only if a
>   bitwise operation (AND, OR, EXCLUSIVE OR) is to be performed on a
>   numeric value.

This way, if you want to have multiple options set you can use:

```
var combined =  EAccountStatus.FreeServiceApproved  | EAccountStatus.GovernmentAccount
```

which is equivalent to:

```
  00000001  // =1 - FreeServiceApproved 
| 00000010  // =2 - GovernmentAccount 
 ---------
  00000011  //= 3 - FreeServiceApproved  and  GovernmentAccount
```

[this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c) has a rather good explanation about the `flags attribute`

Comment: Thanks Avi, that was beautifully explained :)

Comment: :) I'm glad I could be of help.

Comment: There shouldn't be an ALL ("all flags") option on FLAGS. The combination of all the flags here would be 7, not 8, which results in 2 values meaning ALL. A solution to this is to binary OR all options, but a bug will almost certainly appear when another enum is added and a dev doesn't update the ALL enum. Another problem is if the value 8 is used when storing data, then the flag enum EAccountStatus is effectively sealed meaning no more options can be added without modifying stored data. Besides reporting, it's rare that you will need to check for ALL.

Comment: @Dan Agreed. The answer was simply using the example used in the original question.

Comment: @AviTurner no worries, it wasn't really at you. Was leaving it here for people that don't know better

Comment: I read a handful of bitwise shift articles and watched a video, explaining how the bits get shifted.. all the while missing the context of why we'd do this in the first place. This answer was exactly what I needed to read.

Answer (score 3):

`<<` is doing simply what does i.e. Shift left operation.

As far as `why in an enum` is concerned, its just a way of evaluating the expression as enums allow expressions (*and evaluate them on compile time*)

Comment: Thanks, but why? Why a shift left operation on an enum?

Comment: @JoelMin because it is a easy way to calculate 1, 2, 4. When using `[Flags]` you want only a single bit set. When you do `1 << 0` only the 0th bit will be set, when you do `1 << 2` only the 2nd bit will be set, and so on.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain explained it so well. Hope you understood it now!

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer!! +1

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Interesting. Is there any runtime advantage, or would you expect the compiler to clean it up anyhow?

Comment: @Bernhard it would be a compile time constant, it is the same way the compiler will turn `int val = 1+1;` to `int val = 2;` when compiled