# how to specify an underlying type for enum in F#

Tags: c#, .net-core, f#

We can specify an underlying type for enum in C# like this:

```cs
[Flags]
public enum MyKinds : ushort
{
    None  = 0,
    Flag1 = 1 << 0,
    Flag2 = 1 << 1,
    // ...
}
```

1. How can I do that using F# ?

```ml
type MyKinds = 
    | None  = 0 
    | Flag1 = 1
    | Flag2 = 2

    // inherit ushort  // error FS0912
```

2. How can I define enum values using bitwise operator like `1 << 0` in F# ?

```ml
type MyKinds = 
    | None = 0 
    | Flag1 = 1 << 0    // error FS0010
    | Flag2 = 1 << 1    // error FS0010
```

Comment: `The underlying type of the enumeration is determined from the literal that is used, so that, for example, you can use literals with a suffix, such as 1u, 2u, and so on, for an unsigned integer (uint32) type.` - [The Manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/enumerations) - does that help you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use the Bitwise-Shift operator for values in a C enum definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999922/why-use-the-bitwise-shift-operator-for-values-in-a-c-enum-definition)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Awesome ! BTW, if you'd like to post it as an answer, I'll accept it as the answer

Comment: @Sercan Actually it doesn't. I'm actually asking how to do that in F# instead of why should I do that :)

Comment: (though i'm not sure how i feel about writing an answer about a language i have 0 experience in; i just did 10 seconds of googling ;))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use bit shifting, but isn't this even better?

```
type MyKinds = 
    | None =  0b0000us
    | Flag1 = 0b0001us
    | Flag2 = 0b0010us
```

Also, if these are to be used as bit flags, you might want to add the `[<Flag>]` attribute, so that printing the value will show any combination of flags.

Answer (score 2):

As specified in [The Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/enumerations), the underlying type of an enum in F# is determined by the numerical suffix.
So in your case, for ushort (unit16), it would be:

```ml
type MyKinds = 
    | None  = 0us 
    | Flag1 = 1us
    | Flag2 = 2us
```

(suffixes for different number types available [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/literals))

Comment: Thx for yr awesome answer. It really helps. I'm still seeking a way to define value using bitwise operator like `Flag2= 1 << 2`.

Comment: @itminus Bit-Shift operators in F# are just are three times the symbol, but doesn't work with enum. Use the `Flags` Attribute. For example `1 <<< 4` for `8`. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/bitwise-operators