# How to group Enum values?

Tags: c#

How can I group Enum values?
Assume I have an enum like

```
public enum Colors
  {
    LightBlue,
    LightGreen,
    DarkGreen,
    Black,
    White,
    LightGry,
    Yellow
  }
```

Now I want to define some groups of colors, e.g. the light colors (LightBlue, LightGreen, White, LightGray, Yellow) and dark colors (Black, DarkGreen).
So I can ask for groups at different places in my code.
If I remember correctly my Java time I just could add methods to the enums in Java. I think that is not possible in C#. But maybe there are other ways.

Edit1: Of course I can add a Utility class with static member like `IsADarkColor(Colors c)`. But I would like do it without an additional class because I could forget that related class when I need that feature.

Comment: C# is not Java, write classes(in Java even an enum is an object).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I can add a Utility class with static member like `IsADarkColor(Colors c)`. But I would like do it without an additional class because I could forget that related class when I need that feature.

This is when *Extension Methods* come in handy:

```
// Taking Reed Copsey's naming advice
public enum Color
{
    LightBlue,
    LightGreen,
    DarkGreen,
    Black,
    White,
    LightGray,
    Yellow
}

public static class Colors
{
    public static bool IsLightColor(this Color color)
    {
        switch(color){
            case Color.LightBlue:
            case Color.LightGreen:
            case Color.DarkGreen:
            case Color.LightGray:
            return true;
            default: 
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

As long as these two classes are in the same namespace, you can see the static method as if it belonged to the Color class:

```
var color = Color.LightBlue;
if(color.IsLightColor()) {...}
```

(hat tip to @Abdul for making me think of extension methods)

Answer (score 6):

You will need to write this in a class.

Personally, I would recommend reworking this into a `Color` (singular) enum, and a `Colors` class.  The `Colors` class could then include methods or properties which return "groups" of enums (ie: `IEnumerable<Color> LightColors { get { //...`)

Comment: Thanks. I will use that pattern as a fallback if there is no better way.

Answer (score 5):

You may use reflection.

 First you have to mark your categories:

```
public enum Colors
{
    [Category("LightColor")]
    LightBlue,
    [Category("LightColor")]
    LightGreen,
    [Category("DarkColor")]
    DarkGreen,
    [Category("DarkColor")]
    Black,
    [Category("LightColor")]
    White,
    [Category("LightColor")]
    LightGry,
    [Category("LightColor")]
    Yellow
}
```

Then you should create some helper class/extension method in order to fetch that information:

```
 public static string GetCategory(this Colors source)
    {
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = source.GetType().GetField(source.ToString());

        CategoryAttribute attribute = (CategoryAttribute)fieldInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(CategoryAttribute), false);

        return attribute.Category;
    }
```

Finally you can do whatever you what with LINQ:

```
 var permissions = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Colors)).Cast<Colors>()
            .Select(x => new { Category = x.GetCategory(), Value = x.ToString() })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
            .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Select(x => x.Value).ToList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple groupings like this can be managed with Flags and some bitwise math.

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var test = Colors.Red;

            var isWarm = Constants.WarmColors.HasFlag(test);
            var isCool = Constants.CoolColors.HasFlag(test);

            Console.WriteLine(isWarm);  //true
            Console.WriteLine(isCool);  //false
        }

        public static class Constants
        {
            public static Colors CoolColors = Colors.Green | Colors.Blue | Colors.Purple;
            public static Colors WarmColors = Colors.Red | Colors.Orange | Colors.Yellow;
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum Colors
        {
            White = 0,
            Red = 1,
            Orange = 1 << 1,
            Yellow = 1 << 2,
            Green = 1 << 3,
            Blue = 1 << 4,
            Purple = 1 << 5,
            Brown = 1 << 6,
            Black = 1 << 7
        }
    }
```

[Bitwise and shift operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators) --Microsoft)

[Logical and Bitwise Operators in C#](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/logical-and-bitwise-operators-in-c) -- Dániel Szabó/Plural Sight

Comment: I'm a bit surprised the `[Flags]` approach hasn't been mentioned yet, despite five other answer posted over a five year period. Nice job at identifying a gap in the existing responses; that's a much more flexible approach. As an aside, instead of introducing a constants class, you could manage these grouping via an enum of enums (e.g., `public enum ColorPalettes`); outside of that, your code would be virtually identical to what you have now.

Answer (score 1):

There is not sub-grouping of enums, however you can use bitwise operations to achive this to some degree in some cases. (See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159138/c-bitwise-operator-in-enum-custom-authorization-in-mvc) for a decent explanaition)

I would just stick with the utility class to be honest, there's nothing messy about it and it means you can add other descriptions, dropdown operations etc as your site grows.

Comment: Thank you. I don't like flagged enums. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way would be to specify values within a range. For example:

```
public enum Color
{
    LightBlue,
    LightGreen,
    LightGray,
    White,
    Yellow,
    DarkGreen = 100,
    Black
}
```

Then all values above 100 are supposed to be dark colors. You can even add an extension method for that purpose

```
public bool static IsLightColor(this Color c)
{
    return c < DarkGreen;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
 Color c = Color.LightBlue;
 if (c.IsLightColor())
 {
       // do something
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

in C# you can do it as follows ( i m not sure, you really want this or not)

```
public enum Colors
  {
    LightBlue,
    LightGreen,
    DarkGreen,
    Black,
    White,
    LightGry,
    Yellow
  }


public enum LightColors{
   LightBlue = Colors.LightBlue, 
   LightGreen = Colors.LightGreen,
   White = Colors.White, 
   LightGray = Colors.LightGray, 
   Yellow = Colors.Yellow
}
public enum DarkColors{
   Black = Colors.Black, 
   DarkGreen = Colors.DarkGreen
```

}

Comment: That's an interesting trick, but I don't much like the idea of creating values of different *types* which are supposed to represent the same fundamental thing. `if(LightColors.LightBlue == Colors.LightBlue)` yields a compile-time error for example.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior but you can do this by casting as follows if((int)LightColors.LightBlue == (int)Colors.LightBlue)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior here is another way to do this. if(Colors.Red.IsEqual(DarkColors.Red))  and create a extension method "IsEqual" to Enum class as follows 
    public static class extension
    {
        public static bool IsEqual(this Enum color, DarkColors anotherColor)
        {
            return (byte)((Colors)color) == (byte)anotherColor;
        }
    }