# C# call and referencing enums

Tags: c#, enums

I wasnt quite sure how to word the question.. But anyway, here's what I am trying to do.

Let's say I have 2 enums:

```
enum test1 : byte
{
    byte1 = 0x00;
    byte2 = 0x01;
    byte3 = 0x02;
}

enum test2 : byte
{
    byte1 = 0x10;
    byte2 = 0x20;
    byte3 = 0x30;
}
```

I am aware I'm not able to group enums inside of another enum, just trying to describe what I am trying to do.

I want to be able to group them, something like:

```
enum testGroup
{
  test1,
  test2
}
```

And after, be able to call and reference them as such:

```
void main() {
    runTest(testGroup.test2);
}

void runTest(testGroup group)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.byte2);
}
```

Basically, the method will print byte2 for whichever enum I pass as a parameter.

So, for example, I pass test1 as the parameter into runTest, it prints the value of byte2, being 0x01, or I pass test2 as a parameter, and it prints byte2, being 0x20.

What would be a way to go about this?

Comment: what value are you hoping to get from `runTest()`, and what are getting?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299279/how-to-group-enum-values

Comment: You say "I pass test1 as the parameter into runTest", but `test1` is a type, not a value. Are you passing `test1.byte1` or `test1.byte2`?

Comment: Are you trying to group two different enums or are you trying to group two values within the same enum.  I.E.  Could you have one enum and if they return either byte1 or byte2 then it passes?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Neither; he's trying to pass the group of all three bytes, not any one byte.

Comment: @Servy: as in `(int)(test1.byte1 | test1.byte2 | test1.byte3)`?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior If you did that then how would you expect `runTest` to unpack it to get the three different values?  And even if you could figure out a way of doing it, it would be quite complex, and the API would be very hard to use, not be statically validated to be correct, and really very easy to mess up as a caller.  What I've shown in my answer is *much* easier to use for both the caller and the callee, and it's entirely statically typed, so it's not even *possible* to mess it up.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using actual `enum` types, you can create your own types that emulate the `enum` pattern to a degree, by having a private constructor and then a fixed number of static fields each initialized to an appropriate value.  This lets you have something that functions like an `enum` but that doesn't need to encapsulate a single integer type as its value.

```
public class Group
{
    private Group(byte a, byte b, byte c)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }

    public byte A { get; private set; }
    public byte B { get; private set; }
    public byte C { get; private set; }

    public static readonly Group One = new Group(0, 1, 2);
    public static readonly Group Two = new Group(8, 16, 24);
}
```

You can now have a method accepting a `Group`, in which you can pass in `Group.One` or `Group.Two` into it.

Comment: Could make the class generic too, so it would like the type declaration for enums as well.

Comment: @Bauss No, you can't make a class like this generic.  The whole point is that all of the instances, and all of their values, are specified at compile time.  If the type is generic then you wouldn't be able to have all of the values supplied at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum test1:byte
{
    byte1 = 0x00,
    byte2 = 0x01,
    byte3 = 0x02
}

enum test2 : byte
{
    byte1 = 0x10,
    byte2 = 0x20,
    byte3 = 0x30
}
```

test1 and test2 have equal names for different values, but a single enum can't have duplicate names

with `enum testGroup { test1, test2 }` you create an enum with two values 0 and 1, named test1 and test2

try this:

```
enum testGroup
{
    e0 = test1.byte1,
    e1 = test1.byte2,
    e2 = test1.byte3,
    e10 = test2.byte1,
    e20 = test2.byte2,
    e30 = test2.byte3,
}

testGroup tg = (testGroup)test1.byte3;
Console.WriteLine(tg); // prints e2
Console.WriteLine((int)tg); // prints 2
```

Comment: This doesn't allow him to pass a group of either the first three or the last three bytes into a method, without the method needing to know which set of three bytes it was given.